# How to open secondary IFRAME link to Primary IFRAME link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have one main iframe(iframe1) page, inside there are six different div boxes. One of the box(iframe2) contains another iframe from external domain.

Now I would like to open the link of iframe2 to iframe1. How is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless both iframe2 and the main document are on the same domain this will not work due to the same-origin-policy.

Comment: they are on the same primary domain but on different subdomains. one is on testsite.domain.com and the iframe2 is on testsite2.domain.com